# TypeError: A_class_meth() missing 1 required positional argument: 'A_class_meth_var1'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting the following error for my code:

> TypeError: A_class_meth() missing 1 required positional argument: 'A_class_meth_var1'.

What should be modify in "A.A_class_meth"?

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self,init_var):
        self.init_var = init_var

    def A_class_meth(self, A_class_meth_var1):
        print("run")

class B():
    def Start(self):        
        self.B_class_var = A("NAME")
        A.A_class_meth(self.B_class_var)

var = B()
var.Start()
```

Comment: You must *make* ``A_class_meth`` a ``classmethod``. Note that a class method that receives a single instance of said class defeats the point of a class method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and store an instance of your A class inside the `start()` method and then reference that.

Otherwise, the `self.B_class_var` is getting passed as the `self` parameter

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,init_var):
        self.init_var = init_var

    def A_class_meth(self, A_class_meth_var1):
        print("run")

class B():
    def start(self):  
        a = A("NAME")      
        self.B_class_var = a
        a.A_class_meth(self.B_class_var)

var = B()
var.start()

>> run
```

or else, alternatively, as suggested above, make the `A_class_meth` a static method and remove the `self` parameter:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,init_var):
        self.init_var = init_var

    @staticmethod
    def A_class_meth(A_class_meth_var1):
        print("run")

class B():
    def start(self):     
        self.B_class_var = A("NAME")
        A.A_class_meth(self.B_class_var)

var = B()
var.start()

>> run
```